# how to exipt ZeroDivisionError inside a method while updating list in odoo?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, divide-by-zero

I'm trying to return a list to print it In pdf report, and the return gives me correct data but if the product cost is zero, I get

> won_perecnt = (total_won * 100) / total_cost
>
> division by zeroZeroDivisionError: float

I need if the error occurs raise a warning that some product cost must be changed.

here is the code

```
@api.multi
def product_summary(self,):
    product_summary_dict = {}
    data=[]
    if self.date_from and self.date_to:
        order_detail = self.env['pos.order'].search([('date_order', '>=',self.date_from),
                                                     ('date_order', '<=', self.date_to)])
        if order_detail:
            for each_order in order_detail:
                for each_order_line in each_order.lines:
                    if each_order_line.product_id.name in product_summary_dict:
                        product_qty = product_summary_dict[each_order_line.product_id.name]
                        product_qty += each_order_line.qty
                        total_sales = each_order_line.price_unit * product_qty
                        total_cost = each_order_line.product_id.standard_price*product_qty
                        total_won = total_sales - total_cost
                        won_perecnt= (total_won *100)/ total_cost
                        res1= {
                            "name": each_order_line.product_id.name,
                            "sold_qty": product_qty,
                            "price_unit": each_order_line.price_unit,
                            'total_sales': total_sales,
                            "total_cost": total_cost,
                            "total_won": total_won,
                            "won_perecnt": won_perecnt,

                        }
                        data.append(res1)
                    else:
                        product_qty = each_order_line.qty
                        total_sales = each_order_line.price_unit * product_qty
                        total_cost = each_order_line.product_id.standard_price * product_qty
                        total_won = total_sales - total_cost
                        won_perecnt= (total_won *100)/ total_cost
                        res2 = {
                            "name": each_order_line.product_id.name,
                            "sold_qty": product_qty,
                            "price_unit": each_order_line.price_unit,
                            'total_sales': total_sales,
                            "total_cost": total_cost,
                            "total_won": total_won,
                            "won_perecnt": won_perecnt,
                        }
                        data.append(res2)
                    product_summary_dict[each_order_line.product_id.name] = product_qty;
    if data:
        return data
    else:
        return {}
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: You can simply add the condition both place- won_perecnt= (total_won *100)/ total_cost if total_cost > 0 else False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this change:

```
try:
    won_percent = (total_won * 100) / total_cost
except ZeroDivisionError:
    won_percent = None

print(won_percent)
```

Returns `None` when the `total_cost` is zero.

Complete code:

```
@api.multi
def product_summary(self):
    product_summary_dict = {}
    data=[]
    if self.date_from and self.date_to:
        order_detail = self.env['pos.order'].search([('date_order', '>=',self.date_from),
                                                     ('date_order', '<=', self.date_to)])
        if order_detail:
            for each_order in order_detail:
                for each_order_line in each_order.lines:
                    if each_order_line.product_id.name in product_summary_dict:
                        product_qty = product_summary_dict[each_order_line.product_id.name]
                        product_qty += each_order_line.qty
                        total_sales = each_order_line.price_unit * product_qty
                        total_cost = each_order_line.product_id.standard_price*product_qty
                        total_won = total_sales - total_cost
                        try:
                            won_perecnt = (total_won * 100) / total_cost
                        except ZeroDivisionError:
                            won_perecnt = None
                        res1 = {
                            "name": each_order_line.product_id.name,
                            "sold_qty": product_qty,
                            "price_unit": each_order_line.price_unit,
                            'total_sales': total_sales,
                            "total_cost": total_cost,
                            "total_won": total_won,
                            "won_perecnt": won_perecnt,
                        }
                        data.append(res1)
                    else:
                        product_qty = each_order_line.qty
                        total_sales = each_order_line.price_unit * product_qty
                        total_cost = each_order_line.product_id.standard_price * product_qty
                        total_won = total_sales - total_cost
                        try:
                            won_perecnt = (total_won * 100) / total_cost
                        except ZeroDivisionError:
                            won_perecnt = None
                        res2 = {
                            "name": each_order_line.product_id.name,
                            "sold_qty": product_qty,
                            "price_unit": each_order_line.price_unit,
                            'total_sales': total_sales,
                            "total_cost": total_cost,
                            "total_won": total_won,
                            "won_perecnt": won_perecnt,
                        }
                        data.append(res2)
                    product_summary_dict[each_order_line.product_id.name] = product_qty;
    return data if data else {}
```

Comment: You need it in both of the 2 places where you are attempting to perform this division

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in a `try`/`catch` block:

```
try:
    won_perecnt = (total_won * 100) / total_cost
catch ZeroDivisionError:
    print("A warning")
```

Replace the `print()` with something more useful.

Comment: where exactly should I write the that